# Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk

Tags: redis

I get the following error, whenever I execute any commands that modify data in redis

```
Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk.
Commands that may modify the data set are disabled. 
Please check Redis logs for details about the error.
```

I installed redis using brew on mac. How can I get the location of log files where redis-server logs information to. I tried looking for redis conf. file, but couldn't find it either.

What is the default location of [1] redis conf file [2] redis log file.

How do I get rid of the above error, and be able to execute commands that modify data in redis.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581059/misconf-redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots for a way to solve this without restarting or losing data.

Comment: Restarting redis resolved this issue for me, based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581059/misconf-redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots/59392047#59392047

Answer (score 29):

When installing with brew the logfile is set to stdout. You need to edit `/usr/local/etc/redis.conf` and change logfile to something else. I set mine to:

```
logfile /var/log/redis-server.log
```

You'll also make sure the user that runs redis has write permissions to the logfile, or redis will simply fail to launch completely. Then just restart redis:

```
brew services restart redis
```

After restarting it'll take a while for the error to show up in the logs, because it happens after redis fails its timed flushes. You should be seeing something like:

```
[7051] 29 Dec 02:37:47.164 # Background saving error
[7051] 29 Dec 02:37:53.009 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
[7051] 29 Dec 02:37:53.010 * Background saving started by pid 7274
[7274] 29 Dec 02:37:53.010 # Failed opening .rdb for saving: Permission denied
```

After a brew install it attempts to save to `/usr/local/var/db/redis/` and since redis is probably running as your current user and not root, it can't write to it. Once redis has permission to write to the directory, your logfile will say:

```
[7051] 29 Dec 03:08:59.098 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
[7051] 29 Dec 03:08:59.098 * Background saving started by pid 8833
[8833] 29 Dec 03:08:59.099 * DB saved on disk
[7051] 29 Dec 03:08:59.200 * Background saving terminated with success
```

and the `stop-writes-on-bgsave-error` error will no longer get raised.

Comment: Since this was written, the redis configuration file location has moved to `/opt/homebrew/etc/redis.conf`

Answer (score 10):

So I guess it is a bit late for adding an answer here but since I wondered on your question as I had the same error. I got it solved by changing my redis.conf 's **dir** variable like this:

```
# The filename where to dump the DB
dbfilename dump.rdb

# The working directory.
#
# The DB will be written inside this directory, with the filename specified
# above using the 'dbfilename' configuration directive.
# 
# The Append Only File will also be created inside this directory.
# 
# Note that you must specify a directory here, not a file name.
dir /root/path/to/dir/with/write/access/
```

The **default value is: ./**, so depending on how you launch your redis server you might not be able to save snapshots.

Hope it helps someone !

Answer (score 4):

In my case i resolved this issue with below steps

**Cause :** By default redis store data @ ./ and if redis runs with redis user this means redis will not be able to write data in ./ file then you will face above error.

**Resolution :**
Step # 1 (Enter a valid location where redis can do write operations)
root@fpe:/var/lib/redis# vim /etc/redis/redis.conf

dir /var/lib/redis # ( This location must have right for redis user to write)

Step # 2 (Connect to redis cli and map directory to write and issue below variable)

127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG SET dir "/var/lib/redis"

127.0.0.1:6379> BGSAVE -

This will enable redis to write data on dump file.

Answer (score 3):

Steps to fix this error:

Go to redis cli by typing `redis-cli`

```
127.0.0.1:6379> config set stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no
```

after that try to set key value

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set test_key 'Test Value'
127.0.0.1:6379> get test_key
"Test Value"
```

Answer (score 2):

Was going through the github discussion and the proposed solution is
to run

> > > config set stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no
> > > in the redis-cli.
> > > here's the link
> > > https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/584#issuecomment-11416418

Answer (score 1):

Check the following places:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/redis...
/usr/local/var/log/redis.log
/usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

This error often indicates an issue with write permissions, make sure you're RDB directory is writable.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually because permission limits. In my case, it's redis disabled write options.

You can try to run `redis-cli` in the shell, and then run the following command:

```
set stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
```

Comment: This answer should not have 5 upvotes because it is misleading. The "stop-writes-on-bgsave-error" is a redis setting which could be used to ask redis server to stop accepting writes if the bgsave (of dump.rdb) fails. This in turn is to let the user know of such failures. 
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/scaleyourcode/images/blog/redis/config/stop-writes.png

Comment: As old as this is, feel obligated to add that the answer is misleading as stated above. I was able to fix the given error in the question by going into the `redis.conf` file and changing `stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes` to `no`. However I would not do this unless you're strictly using redis for caching and sessions.

Comment: This will raise some restore issues obviously, since writes will go on without snapshotting.

Comment: This should set to "no"  redis 127.0.0.1:6379> config set stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no