# Failed opening the RDB file ... Read-only file system

Tags: linux, redis

I'm trying to perform a save or bgsave on my redis instance to run through the backup/restore process. I'm getting errors when I try to save however:

```
532:M 28 Jun 23:58:30.396 # Failed opening the RDB file backup.rdb (in server root dir /var/lib/redis) for saving: Read-only file system
```

Permissions on the `/var/lib/redis` folder:

```
$@/var/lib$ ls -artl | grep redis
drwxrwxrwx  3 redis    redis    4096 Jun 28 23:58 redis
```

Permissions on the `/var/lib` folder:

```
$@/var$ ls -artl | grep lib
drwxrwxrwx 31 root root  4096 Jun 28 23:44 lib
```

Permissions on the `/var` folder:

```
$@/$ ls -artl | grep var
drwxrwxrwx  11 root root  4096 Jul 18  2016 var
```

Redis CLI output for `config get dir`:

```
1) "dir"
2) "/var/lib/redis"
```

Redis CLI output for `config get dbfilename`:

```
1) "dbfilename"
2) "backup.rdb"
```

Error from redis:

```
532:M 28 Jun 23:58:30.396 # Failed opening the RDB file backup.rdb (in server root dir /var/lib/redis) for saving: Read-only file system
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Also, in case anyone is wondering, the /var/lib/redis/ folder is empty.

Comment: Just to comment that this can also happen if there is not enough memory. In my case, Redis was complaining about a read-only filesystem for /var/spool/cron which was in no configuration file at all. Increasing the VM from 1GB RAM to 2GB and rebooting made it work. Not really a solution, but maybe that saves someone else.

Answer (score 28):

You need to add the following to your /etc/systemd/system/redis-server unit file:

`ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/lib/redis`

Note that `/var/lib/redis` is the default, but if in your `/etc/redis/redis.conf` you set a different `dir` config option, you will need to set `ReadWriteDirectories` to that.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 the unit file is located at `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service`

Comment: Great tip, thanks! I did this and everything worked fine for a while, but then suddenly that line simply disappeared from the `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service` file. Any idea how that could have happened? Is this file automatically regenerated/overwritten in some cases?

Comment: I found out this issue, it turns out this solution is not entirely correct, please see this answer for the correct way to do this: https://serverfault.com/a/943335/498459

Comment: Remember to run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` after the editing the file.

Comment: Do not edit the default unit file. Instead create a drop-in with `sytemctl edit`.

Comment: My config file already has "ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/lib/redis", what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Error says Read-only file system
So, check the mounting (/ or /var) of file system, if it is read only, remount the FS with rw mode(read and write mode)
Take backup of important data before mounting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, the mounting seems okay. Redis server is being run by the `redis` user, and when I `sudo su - redis` I can `touch /var/lib/redis/blah.blah` with no errors, and see the file get created.

Comment: I am always seeing this problem. I've verified by looking at /proc/mount that the directory's filesystem has the `rw` option.