# Redis permission denied while opening dump.rdb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, docker-compose, digital-ocean, sidekiq

I am using official `redis` image with `sidekiq` on `dockers`.

Following are `yml` configurations for `redis` image:

```
redis:
  build: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-redis
  ports:
    - '6379:6379'
  volumes:
    - 'redis:/var/lib/redis'

sidekiq:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec sidekiq
  links:
    - db
    - redis
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  env_file:
    - .env
```

Following is the code of my `Dockerfile-redis`:

```
FROM redis
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

When I build the images everything works fine but after sometime  `docker-compose logs` shows the following `permission` error:

```
redis_1          | 98:C 22 Jan 2019 18:40:10.098 # Failed opening the RDB file dump.rdb (in server root dir /var/lib/redis) for saving: Permission denied
redis_1          | 1:M 22 Jan 2019 18:40:10.203 # Background saving error
```

I have tried many solutions but I am still getting this error in logs. Everytime permission is denied for redis to open `dump.rdb` file. I have also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160753/redis-failed-opening-rdb-for-saving-permission-denied) solution and done follwoing changes in my `Dockerfile-redis` to give `root` permission to `redis`

```
USER root
CMD chown -R root:root /var/lib/redis/
CMD chown 777 /var/lib/redis/
CMD chown 777 /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb
```

I have tried `755` for `dir` and `644` for `dbfilename` but it didn't worked for me. I also tried the above configurations of `Dockerfile-redis` with `redis` user but still I am getting the same `permission denied` error for opening `dump.rdb` file.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Please help me with this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the official redis image is using an applicative user to run the redis-server and not root(which is a security best practice) regardless of USER definition - I extracted this from the image's entrypoint shell script:

```
# allow the container to be started with `--user`
if [ "$1" = 'redis-server' -a "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then
    find . \! -user redis -exec chown redis '{}' +
    exec gosu redis "$0" "$@"
fi
```

when mounting a volume to a container, it is owned by the root user, it will override the default directory in the image's layer along with previous permissions.

It seems that the redis image intentions were not to expose the '/var/lib/redis' dir as a volume, instead they offer [mounting to '/data/'](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis) for persistence:

> If persistence is enabled, data is stored in the VOLUME /data, which can be used with --volumes-from some-volume-container or -v /docker/host/dir:/data (see docs.docker volumes).
>
> For more about Redis Persistence, see http://redis.io/topics/persistence.

Answer (score 8):

After an hour of inactivity Redis will try to dump the memory db to disk.

Redis from the official `redis` image tries to write the .rdb file in the containers `/data` folder, which is rather unfortunate, as it is a root-owned folder and it is a non-persistent location too (data written there will disappear if your container/pod crashes).

So after an hour of inactivity, if you have run your `redis` container as a non-root user (e.g. `docker run -u 1007` rather than default `docker run -u 0`), you will get a nicely detailed error msg in your log (see `docker logs redis`):

```
1:M 29 Jun 2019 21:11:22.014 * 1 changes in 3600 seconds. Saving...
1:M 29 Jun 2019 21:11:22.015 * Background saving started by pid 499
499:C 29 Jun 2019 21:11:22.015 # Failed opening the RDB file dump.rdb (in server root dir /data) for saving: Permission denied
1:M 29 Jun 2019 21:11:22.115 # Background saving error
```

So what you need to do is to map container's `/data` folder to an external location (where the non-root user, here: 1007, has write access), e.g:

```
docker run --rm -d --name redis -p 6379:6379 -u 1007 -v /tmp:/data redis
```

Answer (score 0):

Start docker container from root, example:

```
redis:
  build: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-redis
  user: root <-- REQUIRE
  ports:
    - '6379:6379'
  volumes:
    - 'redis:/var/lib/redis'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the port in server. If it is open to the public then this issue is there which is very strange and difficult to diagnose.