# "Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots" error, not related to permissions / memory / disk space

Tags: redis, resque

I am getting the following Redis error:

> MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently
>   not able to persist on disk.

It is not permissions related, though, since it only starts occurring a certain time after reboot (most recent occurrence was about a day after reboot). When it occurs, the server has more than enough memory and disk space. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Edit: The Redis logs shows this when saving properly:

> [2354] 13 Nov 09:56:16.071 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
>
> [2354] 13 Nov 09:56:16.072 * Background saving started by pid 2194
>
> [2194] 13 Nov 09:56:16.118 * DB saved on disk
>
> [2194] 13 Nov 09:56:16.118 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
>
> [2354] 13 Nov 09:56:16.172 * Background saving terminated with success

and this when the error occurs:

> [2355] 13 Nov 09:15:12.069 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
>
> [2355] 13 Nov 09:15:12.070 * Background saving started by pid 27899
>
> [27899] 13 Nov 09:15:12.074 # Error moving temp DB file on the final
>   destination: Is a directory
>
> [2355] 13 Nov 09:15:12.170 # Background saving error

Comment: Are you sure there's no other information in the logs?

Comment: Log info added to the original question.

Comment: I have checked Related also and haven't found a match yet, as most are related to permissions, memory, or disk space.

Comment: Just ran `config set stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no`, which seems like a temporary workaround for now.

Comment: Does this problem occur after executing this command 

echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581059/misconf-redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots)

Answer (score 5):

We had this same problem, and it turned out someone had "cracked" our server and changed the temp DB path to ".ssh" and the filename to "authorized_keys". We used the following commands in the redis CLI to change those:

```
CONFIG SET dir /original/tmp/directory
CONFIG SET dbfilename temp.rdb
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This gets my site working again for a few hours. Then the db path and filename get changed back and the site is down again. I tried deleting and reinstalling redis but this didn't work.