# redis file being deleted on ./etc folder path

Tags: configuration, redis, server, installation

I accidentally deleted the redis file under ./etc now i cannot seem to connect to the redes serve. is there anyway I could reinstall redis in it? if so how? please help me. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm... It seems to be '/etc'.

You can manually build and install. It is described in https://redis.io/download#installation.

Or reinstall package via package manager like **yum** - if the redis was installed by package manager.

```
$ yum --enablerepo=epel,remi reinstall redis
```

But in your case I think it's okay if you make a /etc/redis/* file like redis.conf. Here is a script run example is installing redis version is 3.2.8 with default setting.

```
$ wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.2.8.tar.gz
$ tar xzf redis-3.2.8.tar.gz
$ cd redis-3.2.8/utils
$ sudo ./install_server.sh
Welcome to the redis service installer
This script will help you easily set up a running redis server
Please select the redis port for this instance: [6379]
Selecting default: 6379
Please select the redis config file name [/etc/redis/6379.conf]
Selected default - /etc/redis/6379.conf
Please select the redis log file name [/var/log/redis_6379.log]
Selected default - /var/log/redis_6379.log
Please select the data directory for this instance [/var/lib/redis/6379]
Selected default - /var/lib/redis/6379
Please select the redis executable path [] /usr/local/bin/redis-server
Selected config:
Port           : 6379
Config file    : /etc/redis/6379.conf
Log file       : /var/log/redis_6379.log
Data dir       : /var/lib/redis/6379
Executable     : /usr/local/bin/redis-server
Cli Executable : /usr/local/bin/redis-cli
Is this ok? Then press ENTER to go on or Ctrl-C to abort.

Copied /tmp/6379.conf => /etc/init.d/redis_6379
Installing service...
Successfully added to chkconfig!
Successfully added to runlevels 345!
Starting Redis server...
Installation successful!
$
```

After then, you should configure other parameters like password, bind, ...

I hope it is helpful.

Comment: hi thank you. I tried yum --enablerepo=epel,remi reinstall redis. but doesnt make any difference at all. also tried,
$ wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.2.8.tar.gz
$ tar xzf redis-3.2.8.tar.gz
but when I go to cd redis-3.2.8/util
is says : -bash: cd: redis-3.2.8/util: No such file or directory

Comment: oops not redis-3.2.8/util but redis-3.2.8/utils.

Comment: how about copying this file http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf into /etc/redis/redis.conf

Comment: still doesn't work. is it possible to remove all redis package and intallation and reinstall redis all over from scratch?

Comment: may I know your OS kinds? please let me know result of uname -a

Comment: thanks its : 83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: for removing: 
sudo apt-get remove redis-server

for installing:
sudo apt-get install redis-server

Comment: [install and configure redis on ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04) may be helpful to you

Comment: thank you so much. I'm new to this, is redis-stable and redis-server different?

Comment: redis-stable means redis stable version. redis-server is for package name for apt-get.

Comment: should I have to install both?

Comment: no. just one. in your case you installed redis by package manager(apt-get).

Comment: ohh, what would you recommend? redis by package manager? or the redis-stable? which is which? (for production purpose btw)

Comment: also, when I tried to do redis-cli ping, it give me this message : MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled. Please check Redis logs for details about the error.
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think package manager version is good for you and production also. Normally package version is easy to manage and little bit older than stable version. But if you are good at managing redis, the choice is redis-stable(build by yourself).

Comment: oh thank you so much for this information. but I wonder why couldn't seem to test redis-cli ping? with this err
MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled. Please check Redis logs for details about the error.

Comment: for MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, you can set config set stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no via redis-cli if you don't want to save(or persist). you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581059/misconf-redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots.

Comment: great! it worked! thank you so much. hey I'm going to create a new issue with redis session can you help me? thanks a lot ^^

Comment: lol here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342251/passing-the-session-data-from-passport-to-redis-in-production thanksssssssssss ^^

Comment: hi are you still there?  lol another thing, when I ran sudo service redis status it gave me this msg :

   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor pre
   Active: deactivating (final-sigterm) (Result: timeout) since Mon 2017-02-20 0
     Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
           man:redis-server(1)
isn't that suppose to be activated? instead of deactivating?

Comment: here:
sudo tail /var/log/redis/redis-server.log -n 100
sudo: unable to resolve host api
18273:M 20 Feb 07:36:23.097 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
18273:M 20 Feb 07:36:23.098 * Background saving started by pid 26916
26916:C 20 Feb 07:36:23.100 * DB saved on disk
26916:C 20 Feb 07:36:23.100 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
18273:M 20 Feb 07:36:23.198 * Background saving terminated with success

Comment: 18273:signal-handler (1487594204) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
18273:signal-handler (1487594204) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
18273:M 20 Feb 07:36:45.064 # User requested shutdown...
18273:M 20 Feb 07:36:45.065 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
18273:M 20 Feb 07:36:45.066 * DB saved on disk
18273:M 20 Feb 07:36:45.066 * Removing the pid file.
18273:M 20 Feb 07:36:45.067 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...

Comment: It is like an user requested shutdown. so how about start again? `sudo systemctl start redis` and check again? `sudo systemctl status redis` [the link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04) is helpful.

Comment: Feb 22 03:30:16 api redis-server[15493]: 19737:C 22 Feb 03:30:16.075 # Failed op
Feb 22 03:30:16 api redis-server[15493]: 15493:M 22 Feb 03:30:16.174 # Backgroun

Comment: Feb 22 03:30:22 api redis-server[15493]: 15493:M 22 Feb 03:30:22.091 * 1 changes
Feb 22 03:30:22 api redis-server[15493]: 15493:M 22 Feb 03:30:22.092 * Backgroun
Feb 22 03:30:22 api redis-server[15493]: 19740:C 22 Feb 03:30:22.094 # Failed op
Feb 22 03:30:22 api redis-server[15493]: 15493:M 22 Feb 03:30:22.193 # Backgroun
Feb 22 03:30:28 api redis-server[15493]: 15493:M 22 Feb 03:30:28.013 * 1 changes

Comment: Feb 22 03:30:28 api redis-server[15493]: 15493:M 22 Feb 03:30:28.017 * Backgroun
Feb 22 03:30:28 api redis-server[15493]: 19743:C 22 Feb 03:30:28.018 # Failed op
Feb 22 03:30:28 api redis-server[15493]: 15493:M 22 Feb 03:30:28.117 # Backgroun
lines 1-19

Comment: I followed the linkyou provide still getting the same error :<

Comment: I tried to sudo systemctl start redis
it only hang up and did nothing

Comment: By checking your log file, `19743:C 22 Feb 03:30:28.018 # Failed op`. yes it was cutted :P, redis failed to open *.rdb file.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581059/misconf-redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots

Comment: There? How about modifing `loglevel debug` in `/etc/redis/redis.conf` and look into `/var/log/redis/redis-server.log`. Then you can find the reason.