# MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk

Tags: redis

I am using Redis and I have the error: MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled. Please check Redis logs for details about the error

Server: CentOS 7 - Vultr

I see same question in here: [MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581059/misconf-redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots)

But, i don't fix it with suggest.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem by executing following commands:

```
$ redis-cli
> config set stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no
```

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581059/misconf-redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots#comment56613153_19581256, this doesn't "solve" the problem, it merely ignores it.

Answer (score 3):

Just need to log into your terminal and run the below commands to restart your services.

This is a non-invasive process that avoids you changing any configuration setting.

```
service redis-server stop

service redis-server start
```