# How to configure Redis cache on local?

Tags: redis, asp.net-core-2.0, stackexchange.redis

I have implemented Redis cache with .net core 2.1 application. Now the issue is I have only development connection string. I want to configure and test Redis cache somehow on my local pc. I have read somewhere that it is possible using chocalatey. So can body refer me any link?

PS: When I tried to run redis cache from development server using vpn, It shown me popup to select "ResultBox.cs" file. So I created new ResultBox.cs file and give it the path, but when I call rediscache.Get() method it opens ResultBox.cs file but nothing happens then. Can anybody tell what is ResultBox.cs for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to configure Redis on local using chocolatey. Use [this](https://dumbjob.wordpress.com/tag/chocolatey-redis/) link. If you face Misconf issues while testing on redis-cli [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581059/misconf-redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots) link will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a local docker redis image. See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uk_faculty_connection/2017/02/21/containers-redis-running-redis-on-windows-with-docker/) and [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/) for reference.