# Why Redis server report an error , redis server run normal and my php framework is Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

ERR Error running script (call to f_a08c9c69b7c07ae2485190873b90d128a23e502d): @user_script:1: @user_script: 1: -MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled, because this instance is configured to report errors during writes if RDB snapshotting fails (stop-writes-on-bgsave-error option). Please check the Redis logs for details about the RDB error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RZSY.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding the related commands, code snippets or configuration infos... Otherwise your issue might be classified as off-topic as defined in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581059/misconf-redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots)