# MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled

Tags: magento2.2

Get continuously this error in var/reports file.
I tried below link solution but still it not fixed.
Can anyone please help me for this as it goes on critical now.

[MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581059/misconf-redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots)

Answer (score 0):

I have written this [same answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61551923/7049436). Posting it here as well

**TL;DR** Your redis is not secure. Use redis.conf from [this link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/4.0/redis.conf) to secure it

**long answer:**

This is possibly due to an unsecured `redis-server` instance. The default redis image in a docker container is unsecured.

I was able to connect to `redis` on my webserver using just `redis-cli -h <my-server-ip>`

To sort this out, I went through [this DigitalOcean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04) and many others and was able to close the port.

- You can pick a default redis.conf from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/4.0/redis.conf)
- Then update your docker-compose `redis` section to(update file paths accordingly)

```
redis:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: redis:6.0-alpine
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    env_file:
      - app/.env
    volumes:
      - redis:/data
      - ./app/conf/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

the path to `redis.conf` in `command` and `volumes` should match

- rebuild redis or all the services as required
- try to use `redis-cli -h <my-server-ip>` to verify (it stopped working for me)