# docker: MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

There are several issues similar to this one, such as:

[Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it is currently not able to persist on disk - Ubuntu Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903982/redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots-but-it-is-currently-not-able-to-persi)

[MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57456455/misconf-redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots-but-is-currently-not-able-to)

but none of these solves my problem.

The problem is that I am running my redis in docker-compose, and just cannot understand how to fix this at docker-compose startup.

The [redis docs](https://redis.io/topics/faq) say this is the fix:

> echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory

And this works when Redis is installed outside of docker. But how do I run this command with docker-compose?

I tried the following:

## 1) adding the command:

```
services:
  cache:
    image: redis:5-alpine
    command: ["echo", "1", ">", "/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory", "&&", "redis-server"]
    ports:
      - ${COMPOSE_CACHE_PORT:-6379}:6379
    volumes:
      - cache:/data
```

this doesn't work:

```
 docker-compose up
Recreating constructor_cache_1 ... done
Attaching to constructor_cache_1
cache_1  | 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory && redis-server
constructor_cache_1 exited with code 0
```

## 2) Mounting `/proc/sys/vm/` directory.

This failed: turns out I cannot mount to /proc/ directory.

## 3) Overriding the entrypoint:

custom-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory


# first arg is `-f` or `--some-option`
# or first arg is `something.conf`
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ] || [ "${1%.conf}" != "$1" ]; then
    set -- redis-server "$@"
fi

# allow the container to be started with `--user`
if [ "$1" = 'redis-server' -a "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then
    find . \! -user redis -exec chown redis '{}' +
    exec su-exec redis "$0" "$@"
fi


exec "$@"
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  cache:
    image: redis:5-alpine
    ports:
      - ${COMPOSE_CACHE_PORT:-6379}:6379
    volumes:
      - cache:/data
      - ./.cache/custom-entrypoint.sh:/usr/local/bin/custom-entrypoint.sh
    entrypoint: /usr/local/bin/custom-entrypoint.sh
```

This doesn't work too.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Was in the same situation. Checked my space usage in Docker and noticed I was out of free VM disk space allocated to Docker.

You can check the same using Docker Dashboard if you have it installed or by running `docker system df`

By raising the VM disk space allocated to Docker or reclaiming disk space by running `docker image prune` to remove dangling images I was able to run Redis normally using docker compose.

Answer (score -2):

**TL;DR** Your redis is not secure

**UPDATE:**
Use [expose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose) instead of `ports` so the service is only available to linked services

> Expose ports without publishing them to the host machine - they’ll
>   only be accessible to linked services. Only the internal port can be
>   specified.
>
> ```
> expose
>  - 6379
> ```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

**long answer:**

This is possibly due to an unsecured `redis-server` instance. The default redis image in a docker container is unsecured.

I was able to connect to `redis` on my webserver using just `redis-cli -h <my-server-ip>`

To sort this out, I went through [this DigitalOcean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04) and many others and was able to close the port.

- You can pick a default redis.conf from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/4.0/redis.conf)
- Then update your docker-compose `redis` section to(update file paths accordingly)

```
redis:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: redis:6.0-alpine
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    env_file:
      - app/.env
    volumes:
      - redis:/data
      - ./app/conf/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

the path to `redis.conf` in `command` and `volumes` should match

- rebuild redis or all the services as required
- try to use `redis-cli -h <my-server-ip>` to verify (it stopped working for me)

Comment: And making redis secure by not exposing the port somehow fixes the overcommit_memory error?

Comment: @Tim this is what worked for me for the same error message. I had also tried the linked questions in the question above and also tried blocking the port from external access using ufw