# Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it is currently not able to persist on disk - Ubuntu Server

Tags: node.js, docker, deployment, redis

I'm using a **container of redis alpine** and **i get this error just in production - on my server.** 
I've found [MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581059/misconf-redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots) and gone through it but none of the advice in there works.

**That's the error message:**

```
    $ node dist/queue.js

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
ReplyError: MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled, because this instance is configured to report errors during writes if RDB snapshotting fails (stop-writes-on-bgsave-error option). Please check the Redis logs for details about the RDB error.
    at parseError (/home/deploy/gympoint/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:193:12)
    at parseType (/home/deploy/gympoint/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:303:14)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at /home/deploy/gympoint/node_modules/beequeue/lib/queue.js:322:14
    at /home/deploy/gympoint/node_modules/beequeue/lib/queue.js:177:21
    at Object.callbackOrEmit [as callback_or_emit] (/home/deploy/gympoint/node_modules/redis/lib/utils.js:89:9)
    at RedisClient.return_error (/home/deploy/gympoint/node_modules/redis/index.js:706:11)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.returnError (/home/deploy/gympoint/node_modules/redis/index.js:196:18)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.execute (/home/deploy/gympoint/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:572:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/deploy/gympoint/node_modules/redis/index.js:274:27)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:287:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:268:11)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the reasons this error may occur is if you use a Redis container without a volume attached to it. To solve this issue, just add the following lines to your docker compose file:

```
volumes:
    - "./redis-data:/data"
```