# Modify redis configs using python client

Tags: python, aws-lambda, redis

We are using redis python client to start a local redis server for unit testing. Sample code here:

```
r = StrictRedis(host="localhost", port=6379)
try:
    r.ping()
except ConnectionError:
    subprocess.Popen("./redis-server")
```

We want to change [a redis config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21484282/3921053) to allow us to run unit tests correctly. Since these unit tests run on AWS Lambda, we don't have direct access to the redis-cli to make any permanent config change.

Is there any way to change redis configuration in the python code?

Note: We are not using any redis.conf for unit test. But if there is a solution using that, we can try that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change redis configuration in python code by using the `config_set` command

```
from redis import Redis
r = Redis()
r.config_set("parameter", "value")
```