# Cannot persist data in redis container from host machine

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, redis

I have docker-compose file with redis and node-app config. Node app can persist data running inside container, but when i run same app in my host machine, redis respond with error:
**MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it's currently unable to persist to disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled, because this instance is configured to report errors during writes if RDB snapshotting fails (stop-writes-on-bgsave-error option). Please check the Redis logs for details about the RDB error.**

```
version: '3.0'
services:
    nodeapp:
        container_name: nodeapp
        image: node-image:latest
        depends_on:
           - redis
        build:
            context: ./nodeapp
        ports:
           - "5001:8080"
    redis:
        container_name: redis
        image: redis:5.0.4
        ports:
           - '6379:6379'
        command: redis-server --appendonly yes
        volumes:
           - ./redis-data:/data
```

I tried use without volumes and without appendonly parameter, not working.

Comment: Potentially read some answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581059/misconf-redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots

Comment: @AndrewNolan Thank you for response. I already tried all possible solutions from this thread

Comment: fixed the issue with simple deleting all containers and processes used redis.